# Discord.js Ban command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get a ban command but keep getting errors and I don't know why my code is not working. I am using discord.js v12

```
    bot.on('message', message =>{

   if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)){
    
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);

    const bUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) 

        if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {return message.reply("You do not have enough permission for this command!")};
        if(!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {return message.reply("The bot does not have enough permissions for this commands")};
        if(message.mentions.users.size === 0) {return message.reply("You need to ping a user!")};

        if (!message.guild) return;

        let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(27);

        const banembed = {
            color: "RANDOM",
            title: `Ban`,
            description: `${bUser} has been banned by ${message.author}`,
            fields: [{
                name: "Ban Reason",
                value: `${banReason}`,
            }],
        }

                bUser.send({ embed: banembed }).
                then(
                 bUser.ban({ reason: banReason })
                (message.channel.send({ embed: banembed })
                )
            )   
    };
});
```

Thank you for taking time to read this!

Comment: By the way, not all discord ids are 18 characters long. Users that were made earlier were at the begging of discord are only 17.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this info

Comment: Have you tried console.loging anything to see if what the problem? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

For `bUser.ban({ reason: banReason })` :

The correct syntax is:

```
bUser.ban(banReason);
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is:

```
message.guild.members.ban(user,{reason: "your reason"});
```

i also suggest doing this asynchronious with an await for example

(in an async)

```
try{ 
await message.guild.members.ban(user,{reason: ReasonString});
}catch (error){
console.log(error);
}
```